# Swift: Compare AnyObject with `is` Syntax

Tags: ios, swift

I want to check if my sender is an Xyz-Object

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
let senderIsBonusProduct = sender is Xyz
```

but I get following error:

> Could not find a user-defined conversion from type 'Int1' to type 'Bool'

Comment: which line cause the error?

Comment: Compiler-Error on second line

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expression `sender is Xyz` is returning a `Bool` depending on if `sender` is of type `Xyz`.  It appears that there is a compiler bug whereby `sender is Xyz` is actually returning a `Int1` that is not getting coerced internally to a `Bool`.

A workaround is:

```
let bonus = (sender is Xyz ? true : false)
```

Comment: this explain what the code does, but why it failed to compile?

Comment: @BryanChen what happens if you explicitly flag the constant as, variously, `Int1` or `Bool`? GoZoner's probably write about a compiler inference bug but that might help make the guess more detailed.

Comment: @BryanChen Compiler bug.

Comment: @GoZoner just wrapping the `sender is Xyz` in parens is enough (at least in the playground).

Comment: Please don't be shy about up-voting.

Answer (score 2):

You can also change it to

```
if let senderOfTypeXYZ = sender as? Xyz {
    // senderOfTypeXYZ is available with the expected type here
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Workarounds aren't required anymore with the Beta 3 release and you can combine the `is` operator with other logical operators.